# Is there a way to apply authentication to every service apart from a single specific service in Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I have the following policy, which integrates with our Auth0 account:

```
apiVersion: authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: auth-policy
spec:
  targets:
  - name: my-service
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "https://<redacted>.eu.auth0.com/"
      jwksUri: "https://<redacted>.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

which applies our Auth0 config to everything, but I want to disable this for a single service. I suppose I want to set targets as 'everything except x'.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using cloud provideder, kubeadm or minikube? Also what Istio version are you using?

Comment: @PjoterS we're using EKS and Istio version 1.2.5

Answer (score 0):

On Policy's `spec.targets` you only specified one service name `my-service` which applies only to one service with this name only. On [Target selector](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#target-selectors) docs you can find information that using this way you need to specify each service name but you can specify also port number. There also mentioned about 3 types of policies:  `Mesh-wide`, `Namespace-wide` and `Service-specific`.

Regarding solution for your question I can advise you 3 options:

**1. Separate namespaces for enabled and disabled services**

You can place your services which should be authenticate to another `namespace`  and enable [namespace-wide policy](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication-policies).  Another variation of this option would be to move services which should not be authenticate to different `namespace` and enable authentication in `default` namespace.

**2. Namespace-wide policy with individual service**
It is similar to previous but instead of creating new namespace-wide policy you just need to create a `service-specific` policy which will disable authentication in one service.

It should work as the priority order is

> service-specific > namespace-wide > mesh-wide

**3. MeshPolicy with Individual service**
If you want to keep all services in one `namespace` you can use [MeshPolicy](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#policy-storage-scope) to apply this policy to all `services` in all namespaces in mesh and then create another `service-specific` policy to disable authentication. As before mentioned `service-specific` has higher priority than `MeshPolicy`.

Hope it will help.